# Unity really slow when playing

Tags: unity-game-engine

It's incredibly slow when I hit play, as in it takes awhile for it to stop if I hit play again, swapping between different tabs is slow, even moving around the unity window itself is slow. Here's my itty bitty singular script, incase I somehow messed up. I've done tutorials before and it was nowhere near this laggy too

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
public class HungerSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hunger;
    public int hungerMultiplier;

    void Update() {
        if (hunger < 1000) {
            hunger = hunger + (1 * hungerMultiplier);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Debug.Log("Me Hungory");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can't use `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Oh ok, why is that, and what are my alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Thread.Sleep(1000); if you want wait 1 second to execute Debug.Log("Me Hungory");
You can use a corroutine or an invoke

```
void Update() {
    if (hunger < 1000) {
        hunger = hunger + (1 * hungerMultiplier);
        Invoke("DisplayMessage",1f)
    }
}
private void DisplayMessage()
{
    Debug.Log("Me Hungory");
}
```

If you want only show the message when the hunger is == or hunger >= 1000 just put and if and use the function display message. You never want to slow an update because the update is called in every frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the complications using Thread.Sleep specifically, but sleep functions are typically not the best way to handle situations from my experience.

I would opt for a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) using a [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) yield instruction. This is Unity's built in system for asynchronous code, and should achieve the same result as what you have posted.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class HungerSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hunger;
    public int hungerMultiplier;

    void Start() => StartCoroutine(DoHungryRoutine());
    
    IEnumerator DoHungryRoutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (hunger < 1000)
            {        
                hunger = hunger + (1 * hungerMultiplier);
                Debug.Log("Me Hungory");
                yield return WaitForSeconds(1);
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code 100% but it doesn't seem to actually wait 1 second, i still get hundreds of logs in command. I just want it to happen once a second, sorry if I should have explained it in the post

Comment: Ah, I see. What I posted was translating your code to use Unity's coroutine system.
I will update my answer to code that would call the log once a second.